# Solution of an implicit Fourier transform equation

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, matlab

How does one solve the following equation ($\hat{a}(k)$ denotes the Fourier transform of $a(x)$ and $q$ is real positive):
$$\hat{a}(k)=f(k)\widehat{a^q}(k).$$
This equation appeared in some paper. Numerically, I tried solving the above equation iteratively. First, I assumed an initial solution for $a(x)$ and then performed fast Fourier transform (FFT) of $a^q$. Then, I took inverse transform of the resulting right hand side of the above equation to get a new $a(x)$. The procedure is repeated until convergence. I could not get a converged solution in MATLAB, where I basically tried the following iteratively:
$$aHat=f(k)\times fft(a^q);$$
$$a=ifft(aHat);$$
Is the above procedure supposed to work? Is there any other way to solve the above equation? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Isn't $a(t) = \hat{f}(-t) \ast a^{q}(t)$? Not sure if that helps you.

Comment: I have no idea it it will work, but it's easy to try. `costfun=@(a)norm( fft(a) - f.*fft(a.^q) ); a_est = fminsearch( costfun, zeros(size(f)) );`.